# removeObserver: forKeyPath is not working

Tags: ios, cocoa, key-value-observing

I have a `UIView` subclass that registers itself and an observer with an object in an `NSDictionary`.

When this view is removed (when its containing view is removed) I call the `removeObserver:forKey` method in the view's dealloc method.

The app will later crash because my view object is not actually being removed from the observers.  I have confirmed this through the dictionary's observationInfo.

I can see that my dealloc is indeed running when I would expect.  This same method is working fine with other subclassed things, like `UIButton` and `UILabel`.

If it helps: The only difference between the other subclassed things and this view is the other things are instantiated from a NIB, where this view is built in code...

Any idea what might be preventing this from removing properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are likely calling `addObserver:forKey:context:` multiple times. You must exactly balance calls to `addObserver:...` and `removeObserver:...`

Where are you calling `addObserver:...`? Are you aware of how nib-loaded objects are instantiated? You probably want to put the `addObserver:...` in `awakeFromNib` or `initWithCoder:`. I often use a `setup` method for objects that might or might not be created from a nib file. For instance:

```
- (void)setup {
  // Do setup work here
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    [self setup];
  }
  return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
  self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
  if (self) {
    [self setup];
  }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: I was using observationInfo to look at what was watching and I don't recall seeing two of my object in there...  I was doing my setup work in `willMoveToSuperView`, but I wasn't really confident that it was a good place.  I couldn't use `initWithCoder` because my call to `addObserver:` depended on properties that weren't set yet.  Moving that setup code into your aptly-named `setup` worked great!  That was such a simple solution, I feel a bit stupid for not doing it.  Thank you very much.

Comment: The other good place to put this call is `awakeFromNib`. That's after all the IBOutlets have been wired up.